# Bootstrap drop down menu extends beyond the screen's width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please take a look at this Link http://jsfiddle.net/bw7k3yee/ Click on where it says "Click Here Please" and notice how the sub-menu extends to the left of the screen.

How Can I fix that please?

Here is the HTML code as well:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse" style="background-color:purple; margin-top:0px;">
     <div class=" container">


         <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeadCollapse">
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>


         <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeadCollapse">


            <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Click Here Please<b class="caret"></b></a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com">This Sub Menu floats extends beyond the width of the screen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com">This Sub Menu floats extends beyond the width of the screen </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu2 Menu2 Menu2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    </ul>
                </li>



                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu 5<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu 7<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="dropdown">

                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu 9<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    </ul>
                </li>


             <li class="dropdown">

                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color:white">Menu 10<b class="caret"></b></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                 </ul>
             </li>   
            </ul>
         </div>

     </div>
     <!-- This creates the login bar on top -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok basically what you will need to do is add the `.dropdown-menu-right` to your menus that are over running on the right hand side. See what I did you on the [updated js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bw7k3yee/4/)

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. Your solution solves half of the problem. It solves the problem for the drop down menu that is on the left-hand side of the page, while it re-creates the problem for the menu that is on the right hand side, see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bw7k3yee/3/     Looks like I am looking for something similar to what you provided me but to be applied on the first or the first and second drop down lists only not all of them.

Comment: hey @crazymatt, submit a new answer with your second option. way better

Comment: I will just edit this answer and remove the first part.

Comment: @Amjad if this helped you please accept the answer or provide more information so others can help you.

Comment: I will apply this fix today and I will provide the feedback.

Comment: <ul class= "nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> You changed this to <ul class= "nav navbar-nav"> And that changes the behavior of my menu. I want something exactly similar to what you just did; but on the other side, so I need to leave the "navbar-right" there and add styling to the submenu on the left hand side not the ones on the right handside.

Comment: If that is the case then change your menus back to the way you had them and for the menus that are running off the page on the left side use "navbar-left".